# Altium Hierarchical design error

Tags: altium

I have a Hierarchical design in Altium and after compiling I am getting and error about `Duplicate NET name wire...`. I searched on Altium articles and here on `electronics.stackexchange` but I can't understand why I am getting the error. Here is a picture of it:

[image]

And here is my project settings:

[image]

I know I have 2 ports with the same name `RX communication` that is the port Altium is complaining about but I have other ports with also the same name:

[image]

And I am only getting a `Warning` (and I think I shouldn't be getting that warning). Can't I have ports with the same name in the hierarchy?

Comment: You can't wire up TX Communication to RX Communication like that.

Comment: How I should wire it?

Comment: To the ports that have the same name. They can't have a different name like you have now. You can change to "TX_FROM_BT" and connect the TX to the RX *inside* the schematic. Same for RX, "RX_FROM_PIC", etc

Comment: Try giving those two nets on the top level explicit names. I suspect that Altium is giving them default names that are derived from the name of the driving port, leading to the conflict.

Comment: You have one RX Communication as an input port and one as an output port, hence the "duplicate" name.

Comment: @dext0rb connecting the ports with the same names worked! The error is gone! Dave Tweed your approach didn't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dextorb mentioned in order for this to work both extremes must have the same name.