# Altium duplicate net names on top sheet

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, altium

I have a hierarchical design and I needed to separate two sections of a circuit that have a lot of nets connected between them, as you can see:

[image: wires between schematic sheets]

Altium in its infinite wisdom appears to have named all of these nets N000-1 by default.

[image]

Now, so far I've been going around this issue by adding net labels, and maybe that's what I should do, but it seems a bit tedious and redundant. Is that the only solution to this? This issue hasn't come up for me when I'm wiring schematic symbols together, just when I'm wiring together sheet entries from ports as shown. I'm pretty new to this top level hierarchy stuff.

I found a similar question ([Altium Hierarchical design error](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/116793/altium-hierarchical-design-error)), but the consensus was that this one was caused by poor choice of net names and the way they were wired together. As far as I can tell, this doesn't apply to my question.

Comment: Did you configure your project to be hierachical in the project options? If yes, try to allow "ports to name net"

Comment: To properly understand what you have done you need to show a picture of the sub-sheet ports.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, it's not due to poor net names at all.
When you have chosen "STRICTY HIERARCHICAL" all port names and nets MUST BE LOCAL.
I've used Altium for years and this error occurs in Altium 19, 20 and maybe 21.